# Delphi 10.2: HTTPClient формирование TIdMultiPartFormDataStream

Tags: delphi, http

Я посылаю из Delphi приложения post запросы используя компонент THTTPClient. Тело запроса формирую с помощью TIdMultiPartFormDataStream. Но в последнем разделе "HTML Form URL Encoded" получается какая-то мешанина заголовков. Ниже код и тело пакета из сниффера.

```
HTTPCommandClient:   THTTPClient;

...

HTTPCommandClient     := THTTPClient.Create;
with HTTPCommandClient do
begin
    ConnectionTimeout  := 10000;
    ResponseTimeout    := 10000;
    CustomHeaders['Accept']           := '*/*';
    CustomHeaders['Content-Type']     := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    CustomHeaders['X-Requested-With'] := 'XMLHttpRequest';
    CustomHeaders['Accept-Encoding']  := 'gzip, deflate';
    CustomHeaders['Accept-Language']  := 'ru-RU';
end;

...

procedure TIPSwitchNetworkPortsForm.ResetAllCountSpeedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var commandFormData: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
    commandFormData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
        commandFormData.AddFormField('all','');
        try
            HTTPCommandResponse := HTTPCommandClient.Post('http://' +
                                fIPAddress + '/clearportsstat?section=STAT', commandFormData);
        except
        end;
    finally
        commandFormData.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Далее тело пакета, которое получилось:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /clearportsstat?section=STAT HTTP/1.1\r\n
    Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
    Accept: */*\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
    Accept-Language: ru-RU\r\n
    User-Agent: Embarcadero URI Client/1.0\r\n
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n
    Content-Length: 175\r\n
    Host: 192.168.10.30\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://192.168.10.30/clearportsstat?section=STAT]
    [HTTP request 5/5]
    [Prev request in frame: 520]
    [Response in frame: 641]
    File Data: 175 bytes
HTML Form URL Encoded: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Form item: "----------110819143947701
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name" = ""all"
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


    ----------110819143947701--
    "
        Key: ----------110819143947701\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
    name
        Value: "all"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Transfer- 
    Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n\r\n----------110819143947701--\r\n
```

А вот то, что я ожидаю получить:

```
HTML Form URL Encoded: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Form item: "all" = ""
        Key: all
        Value:
```